# Unable to fetch data from MySQL database using PHP in Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio

I was doing login and register subsystem of mobile application, I did it by following a youtube tutorial video, the register feature is working well as all the data were successfully stored in the database.

But when I try to login with the username that was already created, it shows a message "Username and password are not exist!", AS doesn't return any error message.I checked all the coding for several times, googled for the answer but I couldn't find any, Thanks in advance! =)

**Now I'm sure that my activity don't have any problem, but the php scripting file

**LocalDb**

```
public class LocalDb {
public static final String SP_Name = "UserInfo";
SharedPreferences localDb;

//Constructor
public LocalDb(Context context)
{
    localDb = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_Name,0);
}

//store user data
public void storeData(Contact contact)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = localDb.edit();
    editor.putString("Username",contact.username);
    editor.putString("Email",contact.email);
    editor.putString("Student_ID",contact.student_id);
    editor.putString("Password",contact.password);
    editor.commit();
}

//get information about which user is currently logged in
public Contact getLoggedInUser()
{
    String username=localDb.getString("Username","");
    String email=localDb.getString("Email","");
    String student_id=localDb.getString("Student_ID","");
    String password=localDb.getString("Password","");

    Contact storedContact=new Contact(username,email,student_id,password);
    return storedContact;
}

public void setUserLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=localDb.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("loggedIn",loggedIn);
    editor.commit();
}

//Tell user whether is currently login
public Boolean getUserLoggedIn()
{
    if(localDb.getBoolean("loggedIn",false))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
//Clear data when a user log out
public void clearData(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = localDb.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

Here are the php files:

**Register.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "my_db_name" , "my_password" , "my_db");

$username = $_POST["Username"];
$email = $_POST["Email"];
$student_id = $_POST["Student_ID"];
$password = $_POST["Password"];

$insertquery = mysqli_prepare($con , "INSERT INTO UserDetails (Username , Email , Student_ID , Password ) VALUES (? , ? , ? , ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insertquery , "ssss" , $username , $email , $student_id , $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($insertquery);

mysqli_stmt_close($insertquery);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**getUserData.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "my_db_name" , "my_password" , "my_db");

$username = $_POST["Username"];
$password = $_POST["Password"];

$selectquery = mysqli_prepare($con , "SELECT * FROM UserDetails WHERE Username= ? AND Password= ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($selectquery , "ss" , $username , $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($selectquery);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($selectquery);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($selectquery , $username , $email , $student_id , $password);

$user=array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($selectquery);  
(
    $user[username] = $username;
    $user[email] = $email;
    $user[student_id] = $student_id;
    Suser[password] = $password;
)
echo json_encode($user);

mysqli_stmt_close($selectquery);
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Inside your LoginActivity.authenticate() method, the condition (returnedContact == null) is true for some reason when it should be false.  So this returnedContact comes from serverRequest.FetchDataAsyncTask.  For some reason it is returning null.  Sorry I'm probably not any better at coding than you, but maybe this will get you on the right track to trace the problem down.

Comment: A long code ... [mcve] could be help for us to solve your problem

Comment: @BooberBunz I tried to change that part, but it doesn't works, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I certainly can't understand your code but try new Networking Lib.("Volley") for calls. I example for Login and Registration.

```
//Layout of Activity
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="2dp"
tools:context="com.test.test.ScreenOne">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:hint="username"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:hint="password"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/bLogin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save"
    android:id="@+id/bSave"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bLogin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity has 2 buttons and 2 EditText, Login button login via server and Save button saves your data in server:

```
package com.test.test;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ScreenOne extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String URL_LOGIN = "http://IP_ADDRESS/login.php";
private static final String URL_SAVE = "http://IP_ADDRESS/save.php";
private EditText username;
private EditText password;
private Button login;
Button save;
String name;
String pass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_one);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    (login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            request();
        }
    });

    (save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveRequest();
        }
    });
}

private void saveRequest() {
    name = username.getText().toString().trim();
    pass = password.getText().toString().trim();
    final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mDialog.show();

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_SAVE,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOne.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    username.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOne.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> key = new HashMap<>();
            key.put("username", name);
            key.put("password", pass);
            return key;
        }
    };

    NetworkCalls.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
}

private synchronized void request() {
    name = username.getText().toString().trim();
    pass = password.getText().toString().trim();
    final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mDialog.show();

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOne.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    username.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ScreenOne.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> key = new HashMap<>();
            key.put("username", name);
            key.put("password", pass);
            return key;
        }
    };

    NetworkCalls.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
 }
}
```

Singleton class for Volley request:

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

/**
 * Created by W4R10CK on 12-09-2016.
 */
public class NetworkCalls {
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static Context context;

    private static NetworkCalls ourInstance = new NetworkCalls();

    public static NetworkCalls getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private NetworkCalls() {
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request){
        getRequestQueue().add(request);
    }
}
```

API to call server:

```
 //conn.php for connection (file one)
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db_name = "hello";

$con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db_name);

if($con -> connect_error){
echo "Connection error";
}   


//save.php(file two)
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
require_once('conn.php');

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES ('$username','$password')";

if($con -> query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "User added";
}
//$con -> close();
?>
?>

//login.php(file three)
<?php
require_once('conn.php');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if(mysqli_fetch_array($result) == NULL){
echo "Invalid Cred.";
}else{
echo "Success";
}

$con->close();
?>
```

Lastly create one DB named **hello** and table in localhost **user** with 2 fields **username**, **password**.